# mounting drives between Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 machines

Tags: mount, file-transfer

Anyone experienced in mounting a folder on a Windows8.1 machine to a Windows10 machine or vice versa ? My only goal is to copy a lot of user data from one machine to the other, maybe there is a better solution (that I don't know of) ?

Thanks for your help !
Wim

Comment: Are the machines in the same network ? Are they in different physical locations ? Please post more details about your problem, what is the amount of data that you want to copy ? Where are the machines located, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two pcs linked by a network? Do you have access to both, and can you read and write files to both?

If yes, then you should be able to just create a directory on the target pc and copy files as you normally would on your single pc between drives or folders.

Is that what you were asking? Or do you really need to Mount a folder, so it looks like another drive on the network?  Because everything else being equal, you should be able to transfer files just as easily without Mounting it unless you really need to.